# Migrated Workflow models and scripts for 6.3 to 6.5 AEM upgrade, Scripts are not getting picked up

Tags: javascript, workflow, aem, upgrade

I migrated my aem instance from 6.3 to 6.5 and the model got migrated and are working well. But the workflow with scripts are not working because it is not able to pick up the script from the location (checked both before/after migrating scripts to new locations it was through same error). The OOTB scripts are also not getting picked for usage.

> Error:
>   *DEBUG* org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrItemResourceFactory
>   createResource: No JCR Item exists at path
>   '/apps/workflow/scripts/mine.ecma'
>   *DEBUG* org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.helper.ResourceResolverControl
>   Resource null /apps/workflow/scripts/mine.ecma
>   *DEBUG* org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl getResourceInternal: Cannot resolve path
>   '/apps/workflow/scripts/mine.ecma' to a resource
>   *ERROR* com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.rule.ScriptingRuleEngine Could not find script resource /apps/workflow/scripts/mine.ecma.  Workflow
>   Scripts may need to be located in /libs or /apps to be executed
>   *ERROR* com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.rule.RuleEngineAdminImpl Cannot evaluate rule: /apps/workflow/scripts/mine.ecma
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException: Unable to find script
>   resource /apps/workflow/scripts/mine.ecma, make sure scripts are
>   located in /libs or /apps   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.rule.ScriptingRuleEngine.evaluate(ScriptingRuleEngine.jav
>   a:112) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.rule.RuleEngineAdminImpl.evaluate(RuleEngineAdminImpl.jav
>   a:53) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.WorkflowSessionImpl.evaluate(WorkflowSessionImpl.java:136
>   9) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.jcr.WorkItemManager.resolveTransition(WorkItemManager.jav
>   a:963) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.jcr.WorkItemManager.resolveTransition(WorkItemManager.jav
>   a:991) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.jcr.WorkItemManager.getRoutes(WorkItemManager.java:676)
>   [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.WorkflowSessionImpl.getRoutes(WorkflowSessionImpl.java:99
>   3) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.getNextRouteToProcess(JobHandler.java:517)
>   [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:328)
>   [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240]   at
>   org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.JobConsumerManager$JobConsumerWrapper.process(JobConsume
>   rManager.java:502) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]   at
>   org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.startJob(JobQueueImpl.java:293)
>   [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]   at
>   org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.access$100(JobQueueImpl.java:60)
>   [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]   at
>   org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl$1.run(JobQueueImpl.java:229)
>   [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the `jcr:primaryType`? Also, ACLs might be an issue.

Comment: jcr:primaryType is nt:file and what ACL issue might this be? Do I have to add some permissions?

Comment: If you request the file directly via browser, is it returned? Also, compare the properties from 6.3 and 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue. I was getting:

> can't find method
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.InternalScriptHelper.getService(object).
>   (/etc/workflow/scripts/..../*.ecma

I looked at the code and found that there was an error where we were getting resourceresolver and it seems it has changed, so instead of

```
var resolver = sling.getService(Packages.org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrResourceResolverFactory).getResourceResolver(session);
```

used this and error was gone

```
var resolver = sling.getRequest().getResource().getResourceResolver();
```